# GOP Cash On Delivery - Enable Rule when I choose shipping method

Tags: php, opencart

I need a code I can use with "Enable Rule" at GOP Cash On Delivery - Opencart Module - when I choose the shipping method.

For example shipping method information as next :

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="xshippingpro.xshippingpro3" id="xshippingpro.xshippingpro3">
```

When the customer choose this shipping method COD must disabled .

I tried to write code but it does not work

```
if(xshippingpro.xshippingpro3==true) 
{ 
  $enabled=false; 

} 
else 
{ 
  $enabled=true;
}
```

Please help me if possible

With thanks and appreciation

Comment: why  you have written `xshippingpro.xshippingpro3==true` in if condtion.

Comment: I am a beginner and I was trying to write the case (when the shipping method "xshippingpro.xshippingpro3" was selected)